# Can't read property 'map' of undefined in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a simple React app, with crud operations, but I can't even list my objects, which are stored into a sql database. I followed this example for the frontend:  https://github.com/only2dhir/react-js-example
and I continued it, adding the component for my objects.

In my application, I have doctors and patients. A patient is assigned to a doctor, so a doctor can have one or more patients. In order to do this, I create my jsx file, ListCaregiverComponent.jsx, where I did that :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ApiServiceCaregiver from "../../service/ApiServiceCaregiver";
import ApiServicePatient from "../../service/ApiServicePatient";

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

class ListCaregiverComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            caregivers: [],
            patients: [],
            message: null
        }
        this.deleteCaregiver = this.deleteCaregiver.bind(this);
        this.editCaregiver = this.editCaregiver.bind(this);
        this.addCaregiver = this.addCaregiver.bind(this);
        this.reloadCaregiverList = this.reloadCaregiverList.bind(this);
        this.reloadPatientList = this.reloadPatientList.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadCaregiverList();
        this.reloadPatientList();
    }

    reloadCaregiverList() {
        ApiServiceCaregiver.fetchCaregivers()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({caregivers: res.data.result})
            });
    }

    reloadPatientList() {
        ApiServicePatient.fetchPatients()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({patients: res.data.result})
            });
    }

    deleteCaregiver(userId) {
        ApiServiceCaregiver.deleteCaregiver(userId)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message : 'User deleted successfully.'});
                this.setState({caregivers: this.state.caregivers.filter(user => user.id !== userId)});
            })

    }

    editCaregiver(id) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("userId", id);
        this.props.history.push('/edit-caregiver');
    }

    addCaregiver() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("userId");
        this.props.history.push('/add-caregiver');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Typography variant="h4" style={style}>Caregiver Details</Typography>


                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Birth Date</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Gender</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Address</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Patients</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>

                    <TableBody>
                        {this.state.caregivers.map(({ id, name, birthDate, gender, address, patients = [] }) =>(
                            <TableRow key={id}>
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                    {id}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{birthDate}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{gender}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{address}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell align = "right" >Id</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align = "right" >Name</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Birth Date</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Gender</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Address</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Medical Record</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                {patients.map(({ id, name, birthDate, gender, address, medicalRecord })=> {
                                    return (
                                        <TableRow key={id}>
                                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {id}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{name}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{birthDate}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{gender}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{address}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{medicalRecord}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    )
                                })}
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const style ={
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}

export default ListCaregiverComponent;
```

The ListPatientComponent.jsx looks like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ApiServicePatient from "../../service/ApiServicePatient";

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

class ListPatientComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            patients: [],
            message: null
        }
        this.deletePatient = this.deletePatient.bind(this);
        this.editPatient = this.editPatient.bind(this);
        this.addPatient = this.addPatient.bind(this);
        this.reloadPatientList = this.reloadPatientList.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadPatientList();
    }

    reloadPatientList() {
        ApiServicePatient.fetchPatients()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({patients: res.data.result})
            });
    }

    deletePatient(userId) {
        ApiServicePatient.deletePatient(userId)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message : 'User deleted successfully.'});
                this.setState({patients: this.state.patients.filter(user => user.id !== userId)});
            })

    }

    editPatient(id) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("userId", id);
        this.props.history.push('/edit-patient');
    }

    addPatient() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("userId");
        this.props.history.push('/add-patient');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Typography variant="h4" style={style}>Patient Details</Typography>


                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Birth Date</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Gender</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Address</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Medical Record</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="center">Medication Plans</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>

                    <TableBody>
                        {this.state.patients.map(row => (
                            <TableRow key={row.id}>
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                    {row.id}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.birthDate}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.gender}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.address}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{row.medicalRecord}</TableCell>

                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const style ={
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}

export default ListPatientComponent;
```

and it works.

I also added two new js files, ApiServicePatient.js and ApiServiceCaregiver.js :

```
import axios from 'axios';

const CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/caregivers';

class ApiServiceCaregiver {

    fetchCaregivers() {
        return axios.get(CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL);
    }

    fetchCaregiverById(caregiverId) {
        return axios.get(CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + caregiverId);
    }

    deleteCaregiver(caregiverId) {
        return axios.delete(CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + caregiverId);
    }

    addCaregiver(caregiver) {
        return axios.post(""+CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL, caregiver);
    }

    editCaregiver(caregiver) {
        return axios.put(CAREGIVER_API_BASE_URL + '/' + caregiver.id, caregiver);
    }

}

export default new ApiServiceCaregiver();
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

const PATIENT_API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/patients';

class ApiServicePatient {

    fetchPatients() {
        return axios.get(PATIENT_API_BASE_URL);
    }

    fetchPatientById(userId) {
        return axios.get(PATIENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + userId);
    }

    deletePatient(userId) {
        return axios.delete(PATIENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + userId);
    }

    addPatient(user) {
        return axios.post(""+PATIENT_API_BASE_URL, user);
    }

    editPatient(user) {
        return axios.put(PATIENT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + user.id, user);
    }

}

export default new ApiServicePatient();
```

Also, in App.js, I added :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import ListUserComponent from "./component/user/ListUserComponent";
import AddUserComponent from "./component/user/AddUserComponent";
import EditUserComponent from "./component/user/EditUserComponent";

import ListPatientComponent from "./component/patient/ListPatientComponent";
import ListCaregiverComponent from "./component/caregiver/ListCaregiverComponent";

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="container">
          <Router>
              <div className="col-md-6">
                  <h1 className="text-center" style={style}>React User Application</h1>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route path="/" exact component={ListUserComponent} />
                      <Route path="/users" component={ListUserComponent} />
                      <Route path="/add-user" component={AddUserComponent} />
                      <Route path="/edit-user" component={EditUserComponent} />

                      <Route path="/patients" component={ListPatientComponent} />

                      <Route path="/caregivers" component={ListCaregiverComponent} />
                  </Switch>
              </div>
          </Router>
      </div>
  );
}

const style = {
    color: 'red',
    margin: '10px'
}

export default App;
```

It doesn't work, it only says :

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and it indicates the lines with :

```
<TableCell align="right">{row.address}</TableCell>
 {row.patients.map(row => (
```

In the backend application, the class `Caregiver` has a list of patients objects, mapped as one-to-many :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "caregiver", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Patient> patients;
```

Does anyone have some suggestions?

--------UPDATE AFTER FIRST ANSWERS---------

I no longer get that error, but I can't display in my table of caregivers the assigned patients. The corresponding TableCell s are empty for the patients of each caregiver. Why is happening this?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. Start with the line with the `.map()` call that throws the error. Most likely one of your rows in `this.state.caregivers` doesn't have a `patients` key.

Answer (score 2):

You do `this.state.caregivers.map(row =>` and then `{row.patients.map(row =>`, but I don't see any indication that each `caregivers` element has a `patients` array property

Comment: I thought this was the right way, but it doesn't work. That's why I posted here, in hope that someone does know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using asynchronous call the javascript start rendering and for a few miliseconds "this.state.caregivers" has no value so you cannot map a null value it needs to be array null.

Make sure to add a condition to check first or declare "this.state.caregivers" as empty array in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add before each map the property you want to map and `&&` like this:

`this.state.caregivers && this.state.caregivers.map`

Do this for each map in your code.

Comment: If I do this, it will assign all the patients to each caregiver, which is not right

Comment: No this isn't assigning any values, this will just make sure that a given array exists before you map over it. it is a short way of doing a boolean check, if `this.state.caregivers` is undefined it will just skip that map for the time being. hope that makes sense. you can just try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: On which map is the error? `this.state.caregivers` or `row.patients.map`

Comment: On the second one, ```row.patients.map```

Comment: You are calling map on `row.patients.map` but it is undefined you define patients as an array on the state but not on each caregiver

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, `patients` is maybe undefined for some rows, so you could assign it a [**default value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) using [**Destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
{this.state.caregivers.map(({ id, name, birthDate, gender, address, patients = [] }) => (
  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
     {id}
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{name}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{birthDate}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{gender}</TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">{address}</TableCell>

  {patients.map(row => (
   ...
```

Comment: @AnaC Check my answer

Comment: I checked it, I don't get the error, but it still doesn't display the list of the patients, for each caregiver.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it doesn't display the corresponding patients to each caregiver?

Comment: Try to add another question with more details from your backend

Comment: I took the both parts, backend and frontend, from here : https://www.devglan.com/react-js/spring-boot-reactjs-crud-example?fbclid=IwAR0gHrboOvVSr-nD3jGUmpqS7w6nP50rKFgHquu3w2-ll4GcD1qoWMWuaFc . I only added the classes I needed for patient and caregiver, after the model in there.